# How to organize layouts?

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm on the product page and in my layout i created a block to render on the product informations, on the upsell product informations and on the related product informations but it doesn't works.

The problem is caused because my block has multiple childs to render and in layouts i see that if a block has the same name it doesnt works

ex:

```
<referenceBlock name="foo">
    <block class="..." name="something">
        <block class="..." name="athing"/>
    </block>
    <block class="..." name="something else">
        <block class="..." name="athing.else"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="baz">
    <block class="..." name="something">
        <block class="..." name="athing"/>
    </block>
    <block class="..." name="something else">
        <block class="..." name="athing.else"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="bar">
    <block class="..." name="something">
        <block class="..." name="athing"/>
    </block>
    <block class="..." name="something else">
        <block class="..." name="athing.else"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

How i need to organise this ? Should i put a prefix before each name and put an "as" property (like bellow) ?

```
<referenceBlock name="foo">
    <block class="..." name="foo.something" as="something">
        <block class="..." name="foo.athing" as="athing"/>
    </block>
    <block class="..." name="foo.something.else" as="something.else">
        <block class="..." name="foo.athing.else" as="athing.else"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="baz">
    <block class="..." name="baz.something" as="something">
        <block class="..." name="baz.athing" as="athing"/>
    </block>
    <block class="..." name="baz.something.else" as="something.else">
        <block class="..." name="baz.athing.else" as="athing.else"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="bar">
    <block class="..." name="bar.something" as="something">
        <block class="..." name="bar.athing" as="athing"/>
    </block>
    <block class="..." name="bar.something.else" as="something.else">
        <block class="..." name="bar.athing.else" as="athing.else"/>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: How this could helps ? Could you give me an example please ?

Comment: <referenceBlock name="foo">
        <block class="..." name="foo.something" as="foo_something">
            <block class="..." name="foo.athing" as="foo_athing"/>
        </block>
        <block class="..." name="foo.something.else" as="something.else">
            <block class="..." name="foo.athing.else" as="foo_athing.else"/>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

Comment: Yes that's what i did in my second example but i would know if there is a way to do it without duplicating the blocks